# Trying to use GoogleSignIn in React Native then Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-signin

I've enabled the Google SignIn on Firebase using this link https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth My App compiles fine but when I press the Login button and select a Google account for logging in I get the  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR
https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth
I have Windows 10 and

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4
Node : v12.16.0
```

here is App.js

```
    import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react';
    import { Text TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
    import {ButtonTemplate} from '../assets/ButtonTemplate'
    import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
    import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

    const App = () => {

    useEffect(()=> {
        GoogleSignin.configure({
            webClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        });
        })

    async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
            // Get the users ID token
            const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        
            // Create a Google credential with the token
            const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
        
            // Sign-in the user with the credential
            return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
        }
    const googleLogin=()=>{
            console.log('Google SignIn');
            onGoogleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Signed in with Google!'))
            }

    return (
    <ButtonTemplate 
                text={"Continue With Google"} 
                backgroundColor={'#5384ed'}
                fontSize={16}
                marginTop= {'3%'}
                iconText={'G'}
                justifyContent={'flex-start'}
                onPress={googleLogin}
                />
    )
    };

    export default App;
```

Here is the Error

```
    Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: DEVELOPER_ERROR
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2258:45
signIn$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:189098:72
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25048:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25221:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25048:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25121:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25131:21
tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27134:16
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27235:27
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30674:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30713:17
callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30930:33
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2760:35
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2546:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2743:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2545:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had Two issues First one is Above and Second was `An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project.` Second issues was in Firebase while adding SHA1 in project.
I ressolved this issue

1. Delete debug.keystore
2. Then regenerated it by this `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 10000`
3. Then Got SHA1 and SHA256 by this command `keytool -keystore debug.keystore -list -v` after giving password that is located in `android/App/build.gradle then signingConfigs there is store password`
4. Added SHA1 and SHA256 in Firebase my project
5. Download the latest JSON file add that latest JSON in my project `android/App` folder
6. then clean gradle by `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
7. Uninstall App then do `npx react-native run-android`
8. Now its working :)

I used this link [How to Implement Google Login in React Native with Firebase](https://www.pradipdebnath.com/2020/10/06/how-to-implement-google-login-in-react-native-with-firebase/)
also a Youtube video [Youtube Video Related Previous Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdYp5JdMvs0&list=PLQWFhX-gwJbmrCwksjn77tdl36dIWPFAt&index=5&ab_channel=PradipDebnath)

Comment: Blessings to you sir!

Comment: if you still face issues that may be because you have webClientId not correctly configured. For react-native project make sure you are using webClientId of client_type 3 from the google services json

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @Shafqat Bari for your answer

If you can't find your debug.keystore inside `android/app/` directory make sure you have executed this command `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 10000` inside your `android/app/` directory.

Also, if you run the command previously don't run it again instead, see the directory in which you have executed this command and copy the `debug.keystore` from that place into your `android/app/` directory!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you start your app on the emulator, you install debug version, and when you publish the app people install the release version. These 2 versions have different signings, with their own SHA1 and SHA256.
So if you want your app to work in both, you must **pass to Firebase 2 SHA1 and 2 SHA256.**
Use the next command for debug version:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
-storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

For release use the same command but with diff name for keystore ,for example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
    -storepass yourpass -keypass yourpass -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```